# Displaying nested JSON from REST API in table

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having trouble with displaying nested JSON data that I got from my backend server in table.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "personalData": {
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Bobby",
    "personalIdNumber": 852963
  },
  "email": "bobbybob@bob.com",
  "correspondenceAddress": {
    "addressLine1": "Sesame Street",
    "addressLine2": "1",
    "addressLine3": "2",
    "city": "Disney",
    "province": "Cartoons",
    "zipCode": "01-234"
  },
  "companyId": 265385,
  "active": true
}
```

I want to display in table **firstName**, **lastName**, **email**, **companyId** and **active** fields from above.

Here is my get method from class:

```
getData(): void {
    this.service.getAll()
      .subscribe((data) => {
          this.dataList = data;
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

and table HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table" *ngIf="dataList && dataList">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>E-Mail</th>
          <th>Company ID</th>
          <th>Active?</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
          <td>{{data.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{data.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{data.email}}</td>
          <td>{{data.companyId}}</td>
          <td>{{data.active ? "True" : "False"}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openDetails()">Details</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

PersonalData and CorrespondenceAddress is never going to be a list. How can I easily read it and display in table?

Comment: you want also `PersonalData` and `CorrespondenceAddress` for displaying data into table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## JSON Response

If your response look like this in below `json` format then you can make blank array for storing into another array suppose this `JSON` displaying in frontend Eg:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "personalData": {
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Bobby",
    "personalIdNumber": 852963
  },
  "email": "bobbybob@bob.com",
  "correspondenceAddress": {
    "addressLine1": "Sesame Street",
    "addressLine2": "1",
    "addressLine3": "2",
    "city": "Disney",
    "province": "Cartoons",
    "zipCode": "01-234"
  },
  "companyId": 265385,
  "active": true
}
```

create this array for storing backend json response

```
personalData:any=[]; 
correspondenceAddress:any=[];
dataList:any=[];
```

then simply create a method if you want then you can create other wise not need as your wise

```
getDetails(){
   this.personalData = this.array.personalData;
   this.correspondenceAddress =  this.array.correspondenceAddress;

   console.log('this.personalData => ',this.personalData);
   console.log('this.correspondenceAddress => ',this.correspondenceAddress);

   this.dataList.push({personalData: this.personalData, correspondenceAddress: 
   this.correspondenceAddress, array: this.array })

   console.log('dataList =>', this.dataList);
}
```

then simply this method `getDetails()` add into `ngOnInit()` method for automatic call to `getDetails()` when class get initialize

after in your HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table" border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>E-Mail</th>
          <th>Company ID</th>
          <th>Active?</th>
          <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
          <td>{{data.personalData.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{data.personalData.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{data.array.email}}</td>
          <td>{{data.array.companyId}}</td>
          <td>{{data.array.companyId}}</td>
          <td>{{data.correspondenceAddress.addressLine1 + data.correspondenceAddress.addressLine2 + data.correspondenceAddress.addressLine3}}</td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openDetails()">Details</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Here is my stackblitz with `json` [checkout here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9mzxl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

---

## Array Response

If your response look like this in below `array` format then you can go with it

Eg:

```
dataList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      personalData: {
        firstName: "Bob",
        lastName: "Bobby",
        personalIdNumber: 852963
      },
      email: "bobbybob@bob.com",
      correspondenceAddress: {
        addressLine1: "Sesame Street",
        addressLine2: "1",
        addressLine3: "2",
        city: "Disney",
        province: "Cartoons",
        zipCode: "01-234"
      },
      companyId: 265385,
      active: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      personalData: {
        firstName: "Sam",
        lastName: "V",
        personalIdNumber: 852963
      },
      email: "samv@gmail.com",
      correspondenceAddress: {
        addressLine1: "Sesame Street",
        addressLine2: "1",
        addressLine3: "2",
        city: "Disney",
        province: "Cartoons",
        zipCode: "01-234"
      },
      companyId: 265385,
      active: true
    }
  ]
```

then in your HTML look like

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
            <td>{{data?.personalData?.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{data?.personalData?.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{data?.email}}</td>
            <td>{{data?.companyId}}</td>
            <td>{{data?.correspondenceAddress?.addressLine1 +
             data?.correspondenceAddress?.addressLine2 +
              data?.correspondenceAddress?.addressLine3}}</td>
            <td>{{data?.active ? "True" : "False"}}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openDetails()">Details</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Here is my stackblitz with `array` [Checkout](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ormlqd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

hope you will be having array like this

```
dataList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      personalData: {
        firstName: "Bob",
        lastName: "Bobby",
        personalIdNumber: 852963
      },
      email: "bobbybob@bob.com",
      correspondenceAddress: {
        addressLine1: "Sesame Street",
        addressLine2: "1",
        addressLine3: "2",
        city: "Disney",
        province: "Cartoons",
        zipCode: "01-234"
      },
      companyId: 265385,
      active: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      personalData: {
        firstName: "Sam",
        lastName: "V",
        personalIdNumber: 852963
      },
      email: "samv@gmail.com",
      correspondenceAddress: {
        addressLine1: "Sesame Street",
        addressLine2: "1",
        addressLine3: "2",
        city: "Disney",
        province: "Cartoons",
        zipCode: "01-234"
      },
      companyId: 265385,
      active: true
    }
  ]
```

To display the data in table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>E-Mail</th>
            <th>Company ID</th>
            <th>Active?</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
            <td>{{data?.personalData?.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{data?.personalData?.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{data?.email}}</td>
            <td>{{data?.companyId}}</td>
            <td>{{data?.active ? "True" : "False"}}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openDetails()">Details</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```